# ParsePush MasterKey unauthorized

Tags: android, android-studio, parsing, parse-platform

I'm having problems to send push notifications in my Android app. My `main.js` cloud file is this.

```js
// It is best practise to organize your cloud functions group into their own file. You can then import them in your main.js.
require('./functions.js');

Parse.Cloud.afterSave("SendPush", function(request) {


  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  query.exists("deviceToken");

  // here you can add other conditions e.g. to send a push to sepcific users or channel etc.

  var payload = {
    alert: "YOUR_MESSAGE"
      // you can add other stuff here...
  };


  Parse.Push.send({
      data: payload,
      where: query
    }, {
      useMasterKey: true
    })
    .then(function() {
      response.success("Push Sent!");
    }, function(error) {
      response.error("Error while trying to send push " + error.message);
    });
});
```

And the part of my code that send the push is this one.

```html
btnEnviar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //databaseReference.push().setValue(new Mensaje(txtMensajes.getText().toString(), nombre.getText().toString(), "", "1", "00:00"));
                //Base de datos ParseServer
                Mensaje m = new Mensaje();
                m.guardar(txtMensajes.getText().toString(), nombre.getText().toString(), "", "1", "00:00");
                adapter.addMensaje(m);
                listMensajes.add(m);
                m.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Successfully created message on Parse",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            actualizarMensajes();
                            ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
                            push.setChannel(CANALPRINCIPAL);
                            push.setMessage(m.getMensaje());
                            push.sendInBackground(new SendCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void done(ParseException e) {
                                    if(e == null){
                                        System.out.println("PUSH enviado correctamente");
                                    }else{
                                        System.out.println("Fallo en el PUSH");
                                        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                                        System.out.println(e.getCode());
                                    }
                                }
                            });

                            //setScrollbar();
                        } else {
                            Log.e(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),"Failed to save message", e);
                        }
                    }
                });
                txtMensajes.setText("");
            }
        });
```

It always throw the `unauthorized: master key is required`. What I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing?

Comment: The error in your frontend happens because you are trying to send the push directly from the client and it is not allowed. You have to fire your cloud function to send the push instead of sending directly from client.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Based on what I understood from the cloud code you wrote, it looks you just need to create a new object to the SendPush class.

Comment: Do you mean create a java class in my android?

Comment: No. Save a ParseObject: https://docs.parseplatform.org/android/guide/#objects

Comment: Sorry for answering late, but yeah this works for me! thank you